# How do I produce a result in a string? (AS3)

Tags: string, actionscript-3, path-finding

So I am planning to do a mini train map app that tells users the shortest route they are able to take to their destination and which interchanges to stop at to switch trains.

Therefore I followed [this tutorial on pathfinding](http://lassieadventurestudio.wordpress.com/2008/12/09/a-star-pathfinding/) and my train system map is working flawlessly when I trace the Start and End Stations in the function, it outputs the stations that the train is passing through.

My problem is that the function that is being traced is not outputting into a string where I can use a `match()` or `search()` method to detect if interchanges are in the path.

(The thing I need to layout in a string is in the Grid.as file, the `$best` return line at the bottom)

(`$best` will output the best optimal path for the user to travel when you trace the entire function "findpath". For example, it'll output "Abbot Station, Berries Station, Cattion Station")

The scripts in the link is the EXACT ones I have now, the only changes I added was to modify the XML file for the stations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$best.toString() will give you a string version of the path object. Modify the toString function in Path if you want to change what it gives you or even add another function there like toStringBestPath to format the string differently.

Comment: I would like to add that all objects in Flash have an implicit toString() method specific to the object. You can make your own, too! And its a special case where you wouldn't override it, just define it so it doesn't use the internal one.